# How many regions are created by the set of all hyperplanes defined by a set of points?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, matroids

If we have a set of points X in d-dimensional euclidean space, and we look at the set of all n-dimensional hyperplanes that are defined by any subset Y of X (in the sense of being the unique n-dimensional hyperplane containing the points of Y), ranging over all Y in P(X), is there a result for the number of regions defined by this hyperplane arrangement?

edit: I just realized, I'm not sure this makes sense for arbitrary n, only n=d-1.

Comment: You are correct, it only makes sense for $n=d-1$.  Taking $d=3, n=1$, for example, lines cannot cut $3$-space into regions.

Comment: also, you mean for the points to be in general position, don't you?

Comment: No I do not mean for the points to be in general position, although of course I expect that to be the most likely to have a nice answer, and am interested in that as a special case.  Any other special cases would be interesting to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I will recast the question as how many pieces can $d$ dimensional space be cut into by $n$ $d-1$ dimensional hyperplanes.  For $d=2$ it is [A000124](http://oeis.org/A000124), $n(n+1)/2+1$.  For $d=3$ it is [A000125](http://oeis.org/A000125), ${n+1 \choose 3}+n+1$ and the remarks explain why the recurrence is $a(n)=a(n-1)+A000124(n-1)$  The logic carries over to higher dimensions, so that if $a(n,d)$ is the number of regions in $d$ dimensional space created by $n$ hyperplanes, the recurrence is $a(n,d)=a(n-1,d)+a(n-1,d-1)$

Comment: You forgot the n in the first expression.  I can't make the edit because it needs to be 6 chars...

I'm pretty sure this is not an answer to my question.  For instance, if we take 4 points (in general position) with d = 2, we get 6 lines (4 choose 2). 

But I think there will be only 18 regions as opposed to 22 (with general lines)